# What does self.schema refer to in my code?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

My code

```
json_fi = glob.glob("*.json")
table_list=[]
for filename in json_fi:
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as i:
        data = pd.read_json(i, lines=True)
        table_list.append(data)

for table in table_list:
     writer = append_to_parquet_table(table, filepath, writer)

if writer:
     writer.close()
```

Method append_to_parquet

```
def append_to_parquet_table(dataframe, filepath=None, writer=None):
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(dataframe, preserve_index=False)
    if writer is None:
        writer = pq.ParquetWriter(filepath, table.schema)
    writer.write_table(table=table)
    return writer
```

Got error

```
   File "p0.py", line 21, in append_to_parquet_table
    writer.write_table(table=table)
  File "/Users/milenko/djikii/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/parquet.py", line 590, in write_table
    raise ValueError(msg)
```

I looked at parquet.py

```
def write_table(self, table, row_group_size=None):
    if self.schema_changed:
        table = _sanitize_table(table, self.schema, self.flavor)
    assert self.is_open

if not table.schema.equals(self.schema, check_metadata=False):
    msg = ('Table schema does not match schema used to create file: '
           '\ntable:\n{!s} vs. \nfile:\n{!s}'
           .format(table.schema, self.schema))
    raise ValueError(msg)
```

What is self.schema?
I got my parquet file written and .metadata and .schema look OK. Why do I have Value Error?
How to fix this?

Comment: `self` is a keyword in python that methods in a class use to refer to an instance of that class. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/